# How to embed a Github repo/README/Project into a Confluence Page?

Tags: github, confluence

We currently have a Github Project where we're maintaining a list of work in a backlog that we'd like to be able to embed and share through a Confluence page (Atlassian). I tried embedding the page as a iFrame widget in Confluence but that did not work. I also made sure the repo from which the project exists was publicly visible and still didn't work. The GH project looks like this:

[image: ss#1]

Anyone have any ideas on how to do this without involving a marketplace macro/addon to Confluence? Is that the only way?

Comment: All the info seems to indicate you need an add-on.